# SuperSearch Install Error

Tags: error, supersearch, mysql, ee5, database-error

EE 5.2.6

I'm trying to install the SuperSearch module and I'm getting an error.

`SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1071 Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes:`

I'm not sure if this is a mysql setting or something I can change in a config file somewhere. I'm not experienced with this aspect of development at all.

In any case, if someone has an idea how to proceed on this I would really appreciate it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SuperSearch has been obsolete for quite sometime (didn't make it past v2) and will not run on newer versions of EE. Try Low Search.

Comment: Well, I guess that's it then! Thanks, Jim.